# param is missing or the value is empty: incident_datum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I'm new to ruby on rails and I'm having trouble with importing a csv file with data to db. I have been looking around but most of the similar questions on here did not solve this issue.

Problem: param is missing or the value is empty: incident_datum

I understand that this issue is caused by the action controller due to the params.require( but removing it doesn't help because the csv file just gets temporarily uploaded but no data gets extracted from it.

Here are the supporting files =>

Controller:

```
class IncidentDataController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_incident_datum, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /incident_data
  # GET /incident_data.json
  def index
    @incident_data = IncidentDatum.all
    @incident_data_first_20 = IncidentDatum.first(20)
  end

  def import
      IncidentDatum.import(params[:file])
      if @IncidentDatum.save
        # after import, redirect and let us know the method worked!
        redirect_to root_url, notice: "Incident Data Imported!"
      else
        render :new
      end
  end

  # GET /incident_data/1
  # GET /incident_data/1.json
  def show
    @distinct_number = IncidentDatum.distinct.pluck(:number).sort
  end

  # GET /incident_data/new
  def new
    @incident_datum = IncidentDatum.new
  end

  # GET /incident_data/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /incident_data
  # POST /incident_data.json
  def create
    @incident_datum = IncidentDatum.new(incident_datum_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @incident_datum.save
        format.html { redirect_to @incident_datum, notice: 'Incident datum was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @incident_datum }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @incident_datum.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /incident_data/1
  # PATCH/PUT /incident_data/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @incident_datum.update(incident_datum_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @incident_datum, notice: 'Incident datum was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @incident_datum }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @incident_datum.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /incident_data/1
  # DELETE /incident_data/1.json
  def destroy
    @incident_datum.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to incident_data_url, notice: 'Incident datum was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_incident_datum
    @incident_datum = IncidentDatum.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def incident_datum_params
    params.require(:incident_datum).permit(
      :number, 
      :priority, 
      :state, 
      :description, 
      :short_description1, 
      :ticket_type, 
      :task_type, 
      :opened, 
      :closed, 
      :initial_contact, 
      :configuration_item, 
      :environment, 
      :assignment_group, 
      :reassignment_count, 
      :department, 
      :name, 
      :problem, 
      :short_description2)
    #MG what to do with '.require(:incident_datum)' after params?
  end

end
```

Import:

```
<div id="import" class="well" style="display:inline-block;width:100%">
    <h3 style="margin-top:0px;">Import Data</h3>
    <div id="" style="float:left; flex:1;"> 
        <%= form_tag incident_data_path, multipart: true do %>
        <%= file_field_tag :file, :style=>'width: 600px;' %>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; flex:1;">
        <%= submit_tag "Import CSV" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>


<a class="btn btn-info" href="/incident_data/">Incident Data</a>
```

Index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1 style="float:left;">Incident Data</h1><br />
<div class="btn btn-info" style="float:right;">
  <%= link_to 'New Incident Datum', new_incident_datum_path%>
</div><br /><br /><br />


<div style="overflow-y:auto;height:600px;">
  <%= flash[:notice] %>           <!-- Why was this commented out? </th-->
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Number</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Short description1</th>     <!-- Why was this commented out? </th-->
        <th>Ticket type</th>
        <th>Task type</th>
        <th style="display:none">Opened</th>
        <th style="display:none">Closed</th>
        <th style="display:none">Initial contact</th>
        <th>Configuration item</th>
        <th>Environment</th>
        <th>Assignment group</th>
        <th>Reassignment count</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Problem</th>
        <th>Short description2</th>   <!-- Why was this commented out? </th-->

        <th colspan="3"></th>

      </tr>
    </thead>

    <!----------------------------------------------------------------------------
        [] BREADCRUMS - SHOWS WHERE WE ARE IN THE PAGE
        [] PAGEINATOR - GOOGLE THING THAT ALLOWS YOU TO CHOOSE BETWEEN MULTIPLE PAGES //look on main_page.html 
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------->
    <tbody id="descList">
      <% @incident_data_first_20.each do |incident_datum| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= incident_datum.number %></td>
          <td><%= incident_datum.priority %></td>
          <td><%= incident_datum.state %></td>
          <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#descModal"><%= incident_datum.short_description1 %></td>
          <td><%= incident_datum.ticket_type %></td>
          <td><%= incident_datum.task_type %></td>
          <td style="display:none"><%= incident_datum.opened %></td>
          <td style="display:none"><%= incident_datum.closed %></td>
          <td style="display:none"><%= incident_datum.initial_contact %></td>
          <td><%= incident_datum.configuration_item %></td>
          <td><%= incident_datum.environment %></td>
          <td><%= incident_datum.assignment_group %></td>
          <td><%= incident_datum.reassignment_count %></td>
          <td><%= incident_datum.department %></td>
          <td><%= incident_datum.name %></td>
          <td><%= incident_datum.problem %></td>
          <td style="display:none"><%= incident_datum.description %></td>
          <td style="display:none"><%= incident_datum.short_description2 %></td>

          <td><%= link_to 'Show', incident_datum %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_incident_datum_path(incident_datum) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', incident_datum, method: :destroy, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



<%= render partial: "modal", locals: {zone: @zone} %>
```

routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  #resources :incident_data
  # INDEX
  #root to: 'analysis#main_page'

  # Database Tables
  resources :incident_data do
    collection { post :import }
  end
  root to: 'analysis#main_page' #MG

  # ADDITIONAL PAGES
  get 'analysis/main_page'
  get 'analysis/new_tile'
  get 'analysis/ticket_identification'
  get 'analysis/detailed_view'
  get 'analysis/import_data'
  get 'analysis/test'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html


end
```

Console:

```
Processing by IncidentDataController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lBXX210GVPazui46U8rATpzrXCMJw8DAqb7Hc3WWK2uTU3WGojClRU7+ZKkakCjUblweOV7UpM+FiIvRSNzSng==", "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00000002829388 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20180110-11292-jzqi2l.csv>, @original_filename="incident_datum.csv", @content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"incident_datum.csv\"\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel\r\n">, "commit"=>"Import CSV"}
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: incident_datum):

app/controllers/incident_data_controller.rb:84:in `incident_datum_params'
app/controllers/incident_data_controller.rb:39:in `create'
^C- Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
=== puma shutdown: 2018-01-10 14:20:33 +0000 ===
- Goodbye!
Exiting
```

Thank you!

Comment: to which action you are trying to post? `create` or `import`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're circumventing strong params in the `import` action? You use `params[:file]` instead of `incident_datum_params[:file]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is your Form (if you want keep rails convention), you have to create a IncidentDatum element and create a form for this element like:

```
<%= form_for @incident_data , multipart: true do %>
...
```

With this you create a form like incident_datum : { file: .... }

This format you spec in the `def incident_datum_params` method

```
params.require(:incident_datum).permit( :number , ....
```

Also you need to add `file` to `permit`

```
params.require(:incident_datum).permit( :number , :file , ....
```

You can see the format of your post in your console browser network tab and also in the log you post in the question:

> Processing by IncidentDataController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"lBXX210GVPazui46U8rATpzrXCMJw8DAqb7Hc3WWK2uTU3WGojClRU7+ZKkakCjUblweOV7UpM+FiIvRSNzSng==",
>   "file"=>#,
>   @original_filename="incident_datum.csv",
>   @content_type="application/vnd.ms-excel",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\";
>   filename=\"incident_datum.csv\"\r\nContent-Type:
>   application/vnd.ms-excel\r\n">, "commit"=>"Import CSV"} Completed 400
>   Bad Request in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

You can see `file` direct in the params ( no inside incident_data incident_data: { fiel: .... } )

Comment: I think, @inye found your problem. Your form fields (and in consequence your params) are not named according to Rails conventions. Your field should be `<%= file_field_tag 'incident_data_file', :style=>'width: 600px;' %>`, but it's much cleaner and easier to use Rails' form builder, as inye pointed out above!